# Selecting a surviving population in a "voter" Genetic Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, statistics, genetic-algorithm

I've been working on a genetic algorithm where there is a population consisting of individuals with a color, and a preference.  Preference and color are from a small number of finite states, probably around 4 or 5. (example: 1|1, 5|2, 3|3 etc)

Every individual casts a "vote" for their preference, which assists those individuals with that vote as their color.

My current idea is to cycle through every individual, and calculate the chance that they should survive, based on number of votes, etc.  and then roll a die to see if they live.

I'm currently doing it so that if `v[x]` represents the percent of votes for color `x`, individual `k` with color `c` has `v[c]` chance of surviving.  However, this means that if there are equal numbers of all 5 types of (a|a) individuals, 4/5 of them perish, and that's not good.

Does anyone have any idea of a method of randomness I could use to determine the chance an individual has to survive?  For instance, an algorithm that for `v` votes for `c`, `v` individuals with color `c` survive (on statistical average).

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for. You say you have, for a population size of N, exactly N voters. If everyone just votes for themselves, you want everyone to survive? How many individuals do you want to perish each turn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign your fitness (likelyness of survival in your case) to each individual as is, then sort them on descending fitness and use binary tournament selection or something similar to sample another population of your chosen size.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can weight the probabilities according to the value returned by passing each 
member of the population to the *cost function*.

That seems to me the most straightforward way, consistent with the genetic 
meta-heuristic.

More common though, is to divide the current population into segments, based on 
the value returned from passing them to the cost function.

So for instance, 
if each generation consists of 100 members, then the top N (N is just a user-defined
parameter, often something like 5-10% of the total) members w/ the lowest cost 
function result) are carried forward to the next generation just as they are (elitism).
Perhaps this is what you mean by 'survive.' If so, then again, these 'survivors'
are determined by ranking the members of the population according to the cost function
value and selecting those members above your defined elitism fraction constant. 
The rest (the majority) of the next generation are created either by 
mutation or cross-over.

***mutation***:

```
# one member of the current population:
[4, 5, 1, 7, 4, 2, 8, 9]

# small random change in one member of prior generation, to create mutant that is 
# a member of the next generation
[4, 9, 1, 7, 4, 2, 8, 9]
```

***crossover***:

```
# two of the 'top' members of the current generation
[4, 5, 1, 7, 4, 2, 8, 9]
[2, 3, 6, 9, 2, 1, 6, 4]

# offpsring is a member of the next generation
[4, 5, 1, 7, 2, 1, 6, 4]
```

Comment: I don't really need to know how to make the next generation, that's independent of the problem.  The only issue with taking the top 'N' in this situation is that they'll be all the same, and not allow others in.